# How do I remove token in syntax tree in roslyn. e.g. remove virtual keyword token from property?

Tags: c#, syntax, tree, roslyn

How do I remove token in syntax tree in roslyn. e.g. remove virtual keyword token from property?
Roslyn has `RemoveNode` method but I can't find `RemoveToken` method or a way to remove token.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer. To remove, replace the token with new token of kind none. Awkward but works.

```
var noneToken = SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.None);
node = node.ReplaceToken(token_to_remove, noneToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting an `ArgumentException` when running the above code.  This seems to work (though it may be a bit of a hack):

```
var node = node.ReplaceToken(dotToken_to_remove, SyntaxFactory.MissingToken(SyntaxKind.DotToken));
```